# android : adding external libraries (custom) to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, import

i have an external library project for floating windows and i have to import it to my current project which im working on. 
    I tried several methods by adding jar file and adding the whole project in Project properties ->Java Build path -> libraries. It compiles well, but when i run the app. It FCs and i get `NoClassDefFound` error. where am i going wrong?
Can someone please post steps on how to add library project and run my project successfully?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: @Anjali https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut/tree/master/library .

Comment: As stated [here](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut): `Feel free to send messages or questions to markwei@gmail.com` And you probably missed the [instruction page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531)

Comment: are your project and your library are in same folder?

Comment: layout as in?Sorry, i did not get you

Comment: @Anjali No they are not in the same folder.

Comment: so now how do i import the library to my project/? and not get that eror?

Comment: Import in eclipse and check the checkbox of "copy projects into workspace".

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out myself. Thanks guys for the replies.

Solution : `Rightclick` on your project ->`Properties` ->`Android` Tab -> `Library` -> Import library project and click apply.

Thanks